# Laravel get all rows related to one another in the same table

Tags: sql, laravel

Here i have `file_managers`table that contains information like id, uuid, name parent_id etc. some row may have some sub rows related by `parent_id`. now i want to get all the sub rows for a specific id. for an `id` there may have multilevel sub rows.

[image]

in the picture i want all the related id for 1.
Ex. if i want the related rows for id 1, i need all 2, 3, 4, 5 ids because all are related to id 1.

Relation

```
public function sub()
{
    return $this->hasMany(FileManager::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

I tried few time but could not get the result...

Thanks

Comment: FileManager::with('sub')->find(id). have you tried this ?

Comment: @JohnLobo yes i tried but this one give me first step retrun (ex. only id 3 returns) i need all the related row like 3, 4, 5

Comment: try `return $this->hasMany(FileManager::class, 'id', 'parent_id');`

Answer (score 0):

use relationship recursively

```
public function sub(){
    return $this->hasMany(FileManager::class, 'parent_id');
}
    
public function recursiveSub(){
  return $this->sub()->with('recursiveSub');
}
```

and then in the query

```
FileManager::with('recursiveSub')->find($id)
```

Comment: Thanks but this one gives me the data inside the relationship mentioned `recursiveSub` .

i needed the result without relationship, just all the row return

Comment: can you share sql with data so i can try

Comment: INSERT INTO file_managers (id, name, parent_id) values (1, 'Folder 1', null), (2, 'Folder 2', 1), (3, 'Folder 3', 1), (4, 'Folder 4', 2), (5, 'Folder 5', 2)

Comment: @muntasir. in relationship you cant get result like as you expected .you have to use loop